# Не ототбражаются компоненты в созданном виджете(Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

Создал свой виджет(окно) добавил в него кнопку и лэйбл. Само окно появляется, но кнопка и лейбл не отображаются

customwidget.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMWIDGET_H
#define CUSTOMWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>


class CustomWidget:public QWidget
{
public:
    CustomWidget(QWidget* pwgt = 0);
    ~CustomWidget();
};

#endif // CUSTOMWIDGET_H
```

customwidget.cpp

```
#include "customwidget.h"
#include <QtWidgets>

CustomWidget::CustomWidget(QWidget* pwgt):QWidget(pwgt)
{
    QLabel label("label");
    QPushButton button("button");
    QHBoxLayout lay;
    lay.setMargin(10);
    lay.setSpacing(20);
    lay.addWidget(&label);
    lay.addWidget(&button);
    setLayout(&lay);
}
CustomWidget::~CustomWidget() {}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "customwidget.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CustomWidget cw;
    cw.resize(500,500);
    cw.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут вы в автоматической памяти создаете элемент.

```
QLabel label("label");
```

А тут передаете компоновщику указатель на этот элемент.

```
lay.addWidget(&label);
```

Но как только произойдет выход из текущей зоны видимости (конструктора в вашем случае), вся память стека будет высвобождена, объекты удалены.

Поэтому, на момент отрисовки окна, эти элементы уже удалены, вы получаете пустое окно.
Используйте динамическую память:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel("label");
lay.addWidget(label);
```

---

P.S. Как подсказывает gil9red, распространенной практикой является представление элементов окна как полей класса.

В `customwidget.h`:

```
class CustomWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    CustomWidget(QWidget* pwgt = 0);
    ~CustomWidget();
private:
    QLabel *label;
};
```

В `customwidget.cpp`:

```
CustomWidget::CustomWidget(QWidget* pwgt)
    : QWidget(pwgt)
    , label(new QLabel("label"))
{
 ...
}
```

---

Или сразу так в `customwidget.h`:

```
class CustomWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    CustomWidget(QWidget* pwgt = 0);
    ~CustomWidget();
private:
    QLabel label("label");
};
```

При создании объекта элементы будут созданы автоматически, их время жизни будет равно времени жизни всего объекта. В конструкторе останется только организовать компоновку элементов и организацию сигнально-слотовых связей.

Comment: Опередили :) Добавьте, пожалуйста, еще то, что можно создавайте объекты в полях класса (.h) без выделения памяти (`new`)

Comment: @mkkik спасибо за ответ и объяснения.

Comment: @gil9red, не совсем понял, как без выделения памяти?

Comment: @mkkik, у самого класса виджета создаем поля (в заголовочном файле .h) как у автора `QLabel label("label");`, `QPushButton button("button");`, `QHBoxLayout lay;` они будут существовать пока объект класса существует. Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager/blob/master/FadLineEdit/fadclearlineedit.h#L33

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, добавил. Но от себя хочу добавить, что практика не самая хорошая, потому что в заголовок класса попадает не только описание, но и часть реализации. Это может быть неудобно, если интерфейс содержит множество элементов, или они имеют более сложные конструкторы.

Comment: @mkkik, согласен